# Efficient and better way of looping a list and a dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have following TestDataDto.

1. ```
   public class TestDataDto
   {
      public int ProgramId { get; set; }
      public string ProgramName { get; set; }
      public bool IsEnable { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. List of TestDataDto without IsEnable being set

   ```
   var testDatas = new List<TestDataDto>
       {
           new TestDataDto {ProgramId = 1, ProgramName = "Abc"},
           new TestDataDto {ProgramId = 2, ProgramName = "xyz"},
           new TestDataDto {ProgramId = 3, ProgramName = "jkl"},
       };
   ```
3. Dictionary of test data specifying which program id is enable

   ```
   var enableTestData = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
       enableTestData[1] = false;
       enableTestData[2] = true;
       enableTestData[3] = true;
   ```

Now, I have to set IsEnable property of the items of testDatas depending on corresponding program ids in enableTestData dictionary.

I can do this like this.

```
   foreach (var b in enableTestData)
        {
            foreach (var testDataDto in testDatas)
            {
                if (testDataDto.ProgramId == b.Key)
                {
                    testDataDto.IsEnable = b.Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

But does not seem to be the efficient way or rather code does not look good :-(. Can someone please guide me what will be the best way to achive this?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  testDatas.ForEach(d => d.IsEnable = enableTestData[d.ProgramId]);
```

or safe way:

```
testDatas.ForEach(d => d.IsEnable = enableTestData.ContainsKey(d.ProgramId) && enableTestData[d.ProgramId]);
```

Same O(n) as @MarcinJuraszek answer but maybe shorter code.

Comment: This is painful plagiarism of the (now deleted) above answer and is still woefully inefficient and dangerous in comparison to Marcin's answer.

Comment: + you're doing 2 lookups :)

Comment: Yeah, but as you stated @MarcinJuraszek they are O(1) _[which technically is not true]_ so we don't care.

Answer (score 8):

There is a better way. Instead of iterating over entire dictionary use `TryGetValue` to check if value you're looking for exists:

```
foreach (var testDataDto in testDatas)
{
    bool value;
    testDatas.TryGetValue(testDataDto.ProgramId, out value);
    testDataDto.IsEnabled = value;
}
```

Because lookup in `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is an *O(1)* operation it changes your *O(n*m)* method into *O(n)*.